Assign a Verilog output state from that of a register
I am new to Verilog. I keep getting this error in vivado programming a basys3 board: Vivado Error
here is my Verilog code, It is a simple state machine that changes state on each clock cycle. below that is my constraints file:
module StateMachine(
output reg[2:0] state, input x, clk, output led0,led1,led2);
 wire sysHardwareClock,scaledClock; 
 parameter S0 = 3'b000, S1 = 3'b001, S2 = 2'b010, S3 = 2'b011, S4 = 2'b100, S5= 3'b101;
 slowClock(sysHardwareClock,scaledClock);
 always @ (posedge scaledClock)
  begin
     case (state)
       S0:state<= S1;
       S1:state<= S2;
       S2:state<= S3;
       S3:state<= S4;
       S4:state<= S5;
       endcase
   end
endmodule


module slowClock(clk, slowclk);
input clk;
output slowclk;

reg slowclk = 1'b0;
reg [27:0] counter;

always@(posedge clk)
  begin
    counter <= counter + 1;
    if ( counter == 25000000)
        begin
          counter <= 0;
         slowclk <= ~slowclk;
    end
  end
endmodule  

Constraints file:
## Clock signal
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W5 [get_ports sysHardwareClock]                            
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports sysHardwareClock]
    create_clock -add -name sys_clk_pin -period 10.00 -waveform {0 5} [get_ports sysHardwareClock]

## LEDs
set_property PACKAGE_PIN U16 [get_ports state[0]]                   
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports state[0]]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN E19 [get_ports state[0]]                   
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports state[2]]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN U19 [get_ports state[3]]                   
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports state[3]]

i tried changing the errors to warnings and that did nothing

The error notifies you that the led0 output is not connected to anything inside the StateMachine module.  All output ports should be driven from logic inside the module.  The same is true for the other 2 outputs: led1, led2
The x input is also unconnected, as well as other problems.
You should start with running Verilog simulations which would have also informed you of a problem.

The tool is telling you about missing, extra, and overlapping constraints during the bitgen DRC; you have a bigger problem because the design is basically empty after synthesis.
Synthesis optimizes/removes all of your logic because nothing was connected from input to output.
I modified the StateMachine design so that things are connected.
There is no need for two clocks here , use one clock and an enable.  Two clocks introduces several complexities which are completely unnecessary in this case.  I put everything on clk which is an input and also connects the logic to the outside world (outside this module).  I used the synchronous slowclk output of the slowClock module as an enable to change the state in the StateMachine module one time every 2500000 clks.
I added a state to transitions5 back to s0 so that the state pattern re-circulates rather than going from s0-s5 one time and stop.
Constraints file variable state[0], was associated with more than one PACKAGE_PIN constraint.  That's not whats needed for your design.  You also have one too many constraints (removed one).  When you had unused ports, the tool was indicating missing constraints.  Fix that by removing the unused ports.
I removed the extra clock input, the unused x input, the unused led outputs, and the now unused local variables so that the tools don't message about them.
I fixed a couple of other things including the slowClock module; compare to your code to see them.
I don't know if this behaves the way you want it to.
I recommend simulating prior to synthesis and implementation as recommended by @toolic.  The further along you go in the design process workflow, the harder it becomes to debug.  Simulation is the first step of verification.
Now you have something that builds and meets timing that you can use as a baseline for further work.
The post synthesis schematic looks like this.

StateMachine module:
module StateMachine(
  input           clk,
  output reg[2:0] state
);

 wire enable;
 
 parameter S0 = 3'b000, S1 = 3'b001, S2 = 3'b010, S3 = 3'b011,
   S4 = 3'b100, S5 = 3'b101;

 // Instance of slowClock module
 slowClock u1 (clk , enable);

 always @ (posedge clk)
  begin
     if( enable )
     case ( state )
         S0:state<= S1;
         S1:state<= S2;
         S2:state<= S3;
         S3:state<= S4;
         S4:state<= S5;
         S5:state<= S0;
       endcase
     end

endmodule

slowClock module: Change slowclk to 1 clk wide pulse to be used as an enable
module slowClock(clk, slowclk);
input clk;
output slowclk;

reg slowclk = 1'b0;
reg [31:0] counter;

  always@(posedge clk) begin
    // A 2 ms flash may not be seen
    // probably want bigger # like 2500000000 
    if ( counter == 25000000 ) 
      counter <= 0;
    else
      counter <= counter + 1;
  end

  always@ *
    // A 2 ms flash may not be seen 
    // probably want bigger # like 2500000000 
    if( counter == 2500000 )
      slowclk = 1;
    else
     slowclk  = 0;
      
endmodule  

Constraints
## Clock signal
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W5 [get_ports clk]                            
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports clk]
create_clock -add -name clk-period 10.00 -waveform {0 5} [get_ports clk]

## state on LED ports
set_property PACKAGE_PIN U16 [get_ports state[0]]                   
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports state[0]]

set_property PACKAGE_PIN E19 [get_ports state[1]]                   
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports state[1]]

set_property PACKAGE_PIN U19 [get_ports state[2]]                   
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports state[2]]

# Don't need a 4th constraint, the design only has 3 state bits
# set_property PACKAGE_PIN U19 [get_ports state[3]]                   
# set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports state[3]]

I ran the Vivado build thru 'generate bitstream' it finishes, meets timing, no errors, and one warning 'DRC CFGBVS-1' about configuration voltage.  I recommend exploring this starting with an internet search of the warning name.  See also the answer by D@n here basys3 forum
